# Search system using contains() in Kotlin and the result difference with string and list

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to do a search system. 
In my code I have a list of objects, each object has a name and also has a list of keywords like this:

```
    data class Sample(
        val name: String,
        val keywords: List<String>,
        // etc
    )
```

Now jumping to where I do the search, I have the following code:

```
    private lateinit var samples: List<Sample>
    // etc
    fun search(keyword: String) {
        val samplesSearch: MutableList<Sample> = mutableListOf()
        samples.forEach { sample ->
            val sampleName = sample.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
    
            val sampleKeywords = sample.keywords.joinToString(
                separator = ",",
                transform = { it.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) }
            )
    
            if (sampleName.contains(keyword) || sampleKeywords.contains(keyword))
                samplesSearch.add(sample)
        }
    }
```

That way, it works the way I want. But I have a doubt if it would be possible to get the same result, without using *joinToString()*...

Without transforming the list of keywords into a single string, the result is not the same because *contains()* works differently between string and list...

```
    fun search(keyword: String) {
        val samplesSearch: MutableList<Sample> = mutableListOf()
        samples.forEach { sample ->
            val sampleName = sample.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
    
            val sampleKeywords = sample.keywords.onEach { it.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) }

            if (sampleName.contains(keyword) || sampleKeywords.contains(keyword))
                samplesSearch.add(sample)
        }
    }
```

Using *String.contains()* just need to have a sequence of characters, without needing the full word.
Using *List.contains()* need to have the full word.

**Update** 
After milgner's answer I got what I wanted as follows:

```
    fun search(keyword: String) {
        val samplesSearch: MutableList<Sample> = mutableListOf()
        samples.forEach { sample ->
            val sampleName = sample.name
            val sampleKeywords = sample.keywords

            if (sampleName.contains(keyword, ignoreCase = true) ||
                sampleKeywords.any { it.contains(keyword, ignoreCase = true) }
            ) samplesSearch.add(sample)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `val sampleKeywords = sample.keywords.onEach { it.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) }` does not do what you think it does.  You need to use `map`, not `onEach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List.contains` will check every element in the list against the argument using the `equals` implementation. If you're looking for a case-insensitive variant, you can use a construct like

```
sampleKeywords.any { it.equals(keyword, ignoreCase = true) }
```